# gridview to excel

Tags: asp.net

work on asp.net vs05.when i export gridview to excel than i get the below error

**RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();**

why i get this error .How to solve it?

```
public void ToExcel()
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Employee.xls";
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
            gvSearch.RenderControl(htextw);
            Response.Write(stw.ToString());
            Response.End(); 
}


 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

//-- added to handle special characters in excel

```
Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
                     Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());

                     gvSearch.EnableViewState = false;
```

//-- added to handle special characters in excel

Add these lines and see if it helps.

```
StringWriter stw = new StringWriter(); 
            HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw); 
            gvSearch.RenderControl(htextw); 
            Response.Write(stw.ToString()); 
            Response.End();  
}
```

It's a shot in the dark.

Comment: i still get this error "RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();"

Answer (score 0):

in aspx page, Change the  following to false : AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="False" and remove Pagesize="10".

Answer (score 0):

This Code Help to solve export Gridview to excel related problem

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = 
        app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
         
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
         
        app.Visible = true;
         
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Excel Sheet Name"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
       
        worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
        
        for (int i = 1; i < Gridview.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = Gridview.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Gridview.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Gridview.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = 
                Gridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```