# Problem exporting GridView with Checkboxes

Tags: asp.net

`work on asp.net vs05`.My gridview have several column,Some of them contain the text and some contain the checkbox **,if i remove the checkbox** then it does not create any error ,**if i don't remove the check box** and want to export in **excel or pdf** then i get the bellow error:

```
  ****RegisterForEventValidation can only be called during Render();****
```

why i get this error .How to solve it?

**my C# code is :**

```
public void ToExcel()
{
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=Employee.xls";
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
            StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);
            gvSearch.RenderControl(htextw);
            Response.Write(stw.ToString());
            Response.End(); 
}


 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
```

yesterday i post a problem name"gridview to excel ".url: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665958/gridview-to-excel/1669977#1669977` i apply this problem answer but it does not work.Help me to export in excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try **[Matt Bereseth](http://mattberseth.com)**'s **[GridView export utility](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html)**. It can manage to export with checkBoxes and with other HTML controls. It does this by replacing the controls with the real values.

[image]
<sub>(source: [mattberseth.com](http://mattberseth.com/WindowsLiveWriter/ExportGridViewtoExcel_1150B/image0_thumb2.png))</sub>

Look at the function, it is self-explanatory. You can download the library and try your own.

```
/// <summary>
/// Replace any of the contained controls with literals
/// </summary>
/// <param name="control"></param>
private static void PrepareControlForExport(Control control)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < control.Controls.Count; i++)
    {
        Control current = control.Controls[i];
        if (current is LinkButton)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as LinkButton).Text));
        }
        else if (current is ImageButton)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as ImageButton).AlternateText));
        }
        else if (current is HyperLink)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as HyperLink).Text));
        }
        else if (current is DropDownList)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Text));
        }
        else if (current is CheckBox)
        {
            control.Controls.Remove(current);
            control.Controls.AddAt(i, new LiteralControl((current as CheckBox).Checked ? "True" : "False"));
        }

        if (current.HasControls())
        {
            GridViewExportUtil.PrepareControlForExport(current);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set EventValidation to false.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="Records.aspx.cs" Inherits="Records" 
MasterPageFile="~/Master.master"  
EnableEventValidation="false"
```