# C# exporting gridview to excel - file won't open

Tags: c#, excel, gridview, export-to-excel

I'm using excel 2010. I get an error that states "The file you are trying to open, is in a different format than specified.....

The file I am trying to open is over 10mb. I can open a file that is much smaller that is exported from a different gridview and I get the same error as stated above. I believe the error is unavoidable without doing some registry magic.

Here is my code and some things I tried. Can anyone assist as to why I can't open it? Could it be something in my gridview?

EDIT: The second I post this I found the culprit. The Checkboxfield is the cause of the issue. I found this on stackoverflow. Will try and use it or find another way.
[Gridview export utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671582/problem-exporting-gridview-with-checkboxes)

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //render the gridview in Excel
        //tried: filename=completereport.xlsx
        string attachment = "attachment; filename=completereport.xls";
        Response.ClearContent();

        //Tried: Response.Clear();

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        //Tried: Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        //Tried: Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        gvCompleteReport.RenderControl(htw);
        //remove hyperlinks from headers of sortable columns and write output
        Response.Write(Regex.Replace(sw.ToString(), @"(<a[^>]*>)|(</a>)", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
        //Tried: Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }

public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {
        //this override allows export to excel from within an update panel
    }

<asp:GridView ID="gvCompleteReport" runat="server" DataSourceID="odsGetCompleteReport"      AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    CssClass="gridview" DataKeyNames="organization, service">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Organization" DataField="organization" SortExpression="organization" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Service" DataField="service" SortExpression="service" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Category" DataField="Material Category" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Material" DataField="Material Accepted" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Acceptance CD" DataField="acceptance_ds" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="County" DataField="County" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="Residential" DataField="residential_fl" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="Commercial" DataField="commercial_fl" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Svc Type" DataField="service_type_ds" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I don't know how to create a workable excel file but I would leverage Excel itself by outputting to CSV then hooking into an excel COM object to open the csv and save it as xls.

Comment: Another option is to create an Excel COM object, create a spreadsheet and then iterate over your datagridview cells entering their values into the spreadsheet cells. Search for 'automating excel c#' to get an idea of how to do it. I bet it'll take you about 20min to get the hang of working in Excel via c#