# From gridview to excel export - How can I get excel what I see in the application?

Tags: c#, gridview

There is a gridview which includes some data.

The header style of that gridview is

```
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" CssClass="GridViewHeader" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
```

How can I export that gridview to excel?
I want to export what I see, colour, filter etc.

when I follow this link
[gridview to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665958/gridview-to-excel)

I get error because it says there there should be form tag which includes runat="server" but when I add it, it gives again error because masterpage has already have a form..

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste this code into your page:

```
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Confirms that an HtmlForm control is rendered for the specified ASP.NET
       server control at run time. */
}
```

This will solve your issue.